# 960.gs Framework + Footer with odd # of members

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

im having an issue with a layout i'm currently styling in CSS with the help of the 960GS framework.

The page is 960px wide, as required by this framework, so that's not the real issue..

I cannot seem to place an odd number of elements (ex: ) in the area specified to be the footer.

There is a wrapper div for the "footer", which is styled accordingly to various examples on how to use the 960.gs framework with custom layouts. I'm using the container_12 class on that wrapper div, which means I should have 12 columns to work with, but, I have an odd number of elements in my footer (as I've said earlier), and that means that I can't really divide the elements by the number of columns available, besides, some of those divs take exactly what is defined on the 960.gs classes in terms of width, although I can "hack" some of the positioning, I can't really make those elements even-spaced :(

Should I use other container classes (16 or 24) in conjunction with the other container_12 classes used before ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using suffix and prefix that is used with the 960GS framework? [more info](http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/the-960-grid-system-made-easy/)
if that dont work then it would probaly be best to use the 16 or 24 grid, but you can't mixed them together. e.g if you pick 16 all the grids have to be styled to the 16 grid

Answer (score 0):

There's also the option of creating specific divs for whatever elements you'd like in your footer. You could then simply put these into a large footer div and then put each of the individual element divs into 12 columns, positioned as inline-block and aligned to center.

This would allow you a good range of flexibility in the number of content sections you have in your footer, without the worry and trouble of placing things into otherwise limiting columns.